# Safari rendering bug with CSS transform - a depth sorting / z-index problem? (works in Chrome)

Tags: css, safari, transform, z-index

For my website I'm using this spiral animation:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/54mu3l/pen/poNrQGW)

This is how it looks like in Chrome (as it is supposed to be):

[image]

And this is how it looks like in Safari:

[image]

The css transform looks great in Google Chrome but in Safari it breaks.

I tried the following (as mentioned in other forums/threads), but without success:

```css
transform: translateZ(0px);
transform-style: flat;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

---

Here are some similar/related questions. But after hours of searching I haven't found any solution (and yes, I tried all the answers I found):

- [Prevent Safari cuts with transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232369/prevent-safari-cuts-with-transform)
- [Safari Rendering Issues on Rotated Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50830605/safari-rendering-issues-on-rotated-elements)
- [CSS transition transform z-index conflict in Safari (Works on Chrome / FF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055505/css-transition-transform-z-index-conflict-in-safari-works-on-chrome-ff)
- [CSS Translate Issue on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42023419/css-translate-issue-on-safari)
- [CSS transform causing div to overlap in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898856/css-transform-causing-div-to-overlap-in-safari)
- [Bug in CSS3 rotateY transition on Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146511/bug-in-css3-rotatey-transition-on-safari/18167565)
- [Why does Safari treats transform translate different when compared to chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180154/why-does-safari-treats-transform-translate-different-when-compared-to-chrome)
- [Why on Safari the transform translate doesn't work correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864790/why-on-safari-the-transform-translate-doesnt-work-correctly)
- [Safari CSS Transition flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010353/safari-css-transition-flickering)
- [CSS TranslateY Animation on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625105/css-translatey-animation-on-safari)

Related Bugs?

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188656
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61824
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=54766
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88587

My code is based on this blog:
https://codemyui.com/spiral-banner-text-animation-using-pure-css/

---

Here is the code (same as here [Codepen](https://codepen.io/54mu3l/pen/poNrQGW))

html:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=3" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=4" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=5" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=6" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=7" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=8" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=9" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=10" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

stylus (css):

```css
$lines = 10;
$duration = 4;

ul {
  perspective: 900px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 800px;
  min-height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  animation-duration: ($duration * $lines) s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: spiral-staircase;
  opacity: 0;
}

for $i in 0 .. $lines {
  li:nth-child({$i}) {
    animation-delay: (($duration * $i)) - $duration s;
  }
}

for $r in 0 .. ($lines / 2) {
  li:nth-child({$r}) {
    right: ($r / 2) rem;
  }

  li:nth-last-child({$r}) {
    right: ($r / 2) rem;
  }
}

@keyframes spiral-staircase {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(40vh) rotateY(-90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  45% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  50% {
    transform: translateY(0vh) rotateY(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0vh) rotateY(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

It seems to be a bug in Safari. But do you guys have a workaround for? **I would deeply appreciate any help!**

Thank you!

Edit:
If you can reproduce the question (which you should be able to do with the provided Codepen - just open the Codepen once in Chrome and once in Safari) and you don't have a solution or answer, I would appreciate an upvote for the question (so more people can see it). Because the problem with this question is: it is very specific and I guess only few people can answer it. Therefore more upvotes get this question more attention - and hopefully a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to work around the lack of z-index support is to avoid having the planes intersect by displacing them on the z-axis.

since we are animating the transform property and we need that property for doing the z-axis displacement we can change the animation to the `img` element instead of the `li` element, and do the displacement on the `li`.

here's a working example:
https://codepen.io/ptcc/pen/qBqyqEj?editors=0100

the changes are basically these:

move the perspective from the `ul` to each `li`

```
li {
    perspective: 900px;
```

move the animation to the `img` and set a translateZ on the `li` based on the index.

```
for $i in 0 .. $lines {
  li:nth-child({$i}) {
      transform: translateZ($i*100px);
  img{
      animation-delay: (($duration * $i)) - $duration s;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! I'm sorry the bounty just expired before I saw your answer...

Comment: Thank you very very much!!! I had a similar bug with the z position and it's solved, is there a way to request the developers of safari to get to the standard on the future?